# Tapestry save file dialog

Tags: tapestry, savefiledialog

I learn the Tapestry version 5. where I built a treemodel, which presents the files inside the catalog.

```
<t:tree t:id="tree" t:model="stuffModel" t:node="treeNode" t:value="classificationNode">
    <p:label>
    <t:if test="treeNode.leaf">
    <a t:type="EventLink" t:event="leafSelected" t:context="classificationNode.name" t:zone="selectedZone" class="prop:leafClass" href="#"> ${treeNode.label} </a>
    </t:if>
    <t:if test="!treeNode.leaf">
            ${treeNode.label}
    </t:if>
    </p:label>
```

By clicking one of the files I build a StreamResponse ( I used the snippet from the jumpstart code ( page: http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/navigation/returntypes1 )

My problem and my question is how do I present a save-file-dialog that will help the user to point the download folder.
In order to really download the file I must make right-click and then choose "save file as..." ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the zone part of the template, as this returns JSON data from the server and causes break up of communication handling.
Relevant post:
http://www.mail-archive.com/users%40tapestry.apache.org/msg75396.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you found an answer on the Tapestry mailing list. For others looking here, see http://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=users@tapestry.apache.org&q=subject:Re%5C%3A+Save+File+Dialog+after+response+building&o=newest

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your code.

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When user clicks button, show the dialog.
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get file name.
        string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        // Write to the file name selected.
        // ... You can write the text from a TextBox instead of a string literal.
        File.WriteAllText(name, "test");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry mate, it's not C#. It is Java and Tapestry the issue